# Voltage on a conductor

Tags: electrostatics

Let us take a cube. It is in neutral state. Now when we add charges on the surface of it, we say that the cube's voltage increases. Also when the cube was in neutral state, its voltage was said to be $0$. What does voltage on the cube actually mean? And why adding charges to surface make voltage of the cube increase? I want to make note that I know the electrostatic definition of voltage but I don't know how the *work done to move a unit positive charge* definition fits here, since I don't see any electric field nor the point charge with respect to which we determine voltage. As this is a continuous body. Please explain the idea intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

One usually speaks of the *potential of the cube* rather rhan its voltage (which is usually defined as the potential difference between two points).

Now, I assume that the OP is talking about a conducting cube, since otherwise we could not be sure that all the points in the cube have the same potential. Electric field inside a conductor is zero, which means that no work is done when moving the test charge within the conductor. The conductor however has a potential in respect to the reference point, meaning that bringing or removing charge to/from the conductor is associated with nonzero work.

Comment: This seems right, if the charge is gradually put on the cube, it's easy to put the first part on, but then after that there is a repulsion to overcome to put more charge on, so work is done for each part of extra charge put on.  It's like pushing against a spring and potential energy is stored by the charged cube.  The cube has a potential and the potential at infinity is zero, the potential difference or voltage is with respect to the cube and infinity.

Comment: What is the reference point you are talking about?In case of sphere it used to be the center,what about this case?

Comment: If you say that the center of the cube is also the answer in this case,what about an irregular body?

Comment: @madness The reference point is usually taken at infinity, although other choices are possible. Important thing is that all potentials are measured in respect to the same reference point, whereas voltage usually means a difference between two points neither of which is reference. But this is a semantic issue.

Comment: Thank you but we define electric potential for points meaning *the work done to bring a unit positive charge from infinity to point $A$* like this. Here we have a conductor which is a continuous body instead of a point. How do we proceed in this case?

Comment: @madness since it is a conductor, any point in it has the same potential.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more?